# MySQL Select Query Won't Work

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have a table of IPs that I have banned from accessing certain things in my PHP script. When I enter my IP into the database (as a string, example "123.4.5.6") and it doesn't seem to echo "banned", when I have clearly entered my IP into the banned database table.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$checkipban "SELECT * FROM banned WHERE bannedip = '$ip'
";
$banquery = mysql_query($checkipban,$con);
if(mysql_num_rows($banquery) > 0)
echo "banned";
}
?>
```

$con is the connection to the database in config.php and it works because other MySQL queries in the script work. The database table is called banned and there is only one column called bannedip.

Comment: check whether your script compiles, check `$ip`, check whether your query succeeded. and what's that trailing `}` ?

Comment: What do u get in $ip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems typo. You missed `=`

```
$checkipban = "SELECT * FROM banned WHERE bannedip = '$ip'";
            ^
```

**NOTE:**

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: I just realized that it has been deprecated and I am going to use MySQLi instead

Comment: +1 for explaining deprecated mysql_* functions.

Answer (score 1):

You left `=` for assigning it to varaible `$checkipban`,

```
$checkipban  = "SELECT * FROM banned WHERE bannedip = '$ip'";
```